# Is is possible for an application to handle the response from a push notification?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

Is it possible to get the user's response from a push notification and create a notification reply? i.e. if a user clicks the view button and views the app, can we take that action and let the sender of the notification know that the receiver has viewed / opened the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, Yes.

When the application starts due to a user electing to from a notification (local or remote) the application is started in a special way so that the application can process the notification.  At this point it can do whatever you want, like send a message back to your service.

See [Handling Local and Remote Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4) for details.